# Why javascript is needed for preloading images?

Tags: javascript, preloading

On [**this**](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480001) site I found some explanation of preloading images stuff.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
Image1= new Image(175,50)
Image1.src = "image1.gif"

Image2 = new Image(25,30)
Image2.src = "image2.gif"

Image3 = new Image(125,80)
Image3.src = "image3.gif"

</SCRIPT>
```

Could someone explain, what is the difference between the above code and the following:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<img id="Image1" src="image1.gif">
<img id="Image2" src="image2.gif">
<img id="Image3" src="image3.gif">
</div>
```

In both cases images are cached and ready to use somewhere on page.

Why we need any special preloading js code ?

Comment: because js can load from the <head> before anything is visible, and it can pre-load on many pages without bloating the html.

Comment: You only really benefit from caching if you want to change an image on the screen - last time I saw code like this was when we did button roll-overs by changing the image being shown.

Comment: I'd say another advantage is that your markup is cleaner using JS. You're not stuff things into the DOM simply for the purpose of pre-loading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advantages I can think of:

- Loops, you only need to specify the image-folder once.
- Better control over when you want to pre-load
- Cleaner DOM

Comment: ok, but all that is not enough as reason to create so many special plugins for preload images.